# Increase column width for Bootstrap 4 table

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I need to increase column width, i tried width-%,PX,rem but that's not working.
I can able to increase the column width if the table have small number of columns but in my scenario if i have more than 15 columns i cant change the width.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

<th scope="col">#</th><th scope="col">#</th>

      <th scope="col" style="width: 500px;">Heading heading'</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>

      <th scope="col">Heading</th><th scope="col">Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

 <th scope="row">1</th><th scope="row">1</th>

      <td style="width: 300px;">jksdfn jhs fjidsh fj id hidsfdsfd</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>

 <th scope="row">1</th><th scope="row">1</th>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>

      <td>Cell</td><td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to increase the third column in the table below, attached image for referene.
[image]
I've used [Always Responsive Bootstrap 4 Table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `min-width` instead of `width`.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">#</th>

            <th scope="col" style="width: 500px;">Heading heading'</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>

            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <th scope="row">1</th>

            <td style="min-width: 300px;">jksdfn jhs fjidsh fj id hidsfdsfd</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <th scope="row">1</th>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>

            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```